# Python Convert column values of 1-50 to 1-10

Tags: python, mapping

I have values in a column that are 1 to 50. What is the easiest way to convert every 5 to scale back to 1-10? (e.g. [1,2,3,4,5] = 1, [6,7,8,9,10] = 2 )

Comment: What are you calling a "column"? Can you provide code to replicate the exact object (and library) that you are using?

Comment: df column in python. So I binned values to be 1-50 but I would like to have an additional column that converts those 1-50 bins to 1-10

Comment: then it's pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input object is unclear, but you need to use a floor division.

Since python counts from 0 but you from 1, first subtract 1, then divide, finally add 1 again:

Example with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np
inpt = np.arange(1, 51)
out = (inpt-1)//5+1
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,
        4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,
        7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
```

In pure python:

```
inpt = list(range(1, 51))

out = [(x-1)//5+1 for x in inpt]
```

In [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(1, 51)})

df['out'] = df['col'].sub(1).floordiv(5).add(1)
```